# You may not have more than 32 total max instances in your project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, gitlab-ci

When deploying firebase functions (google cloud functions gen 1) I am getting an error "You may not have more than 32 total max instances in your project".

I have no idea where I can find how many instances are using right now or why this error is displayed right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems like Firebase servers in `europe-west3` are having problems. I have found some workarounds to fix this:

**OPTION 1:**

I found something about it. It seems like you can decrease the value of `max_instances` in `app.yaml`.

As one answer of [this posts](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6298) says:

> a fix required from the GCP team here. As a work around you
> can drop the maxInstances low enough for critical functions but you
> will need to delete before deploying to get the total count low
> enough.
>
> be careful if you do this workaround. You won't be able to
> deploy back to >32 total instances until someone at Google resolves
> this.

You can check the official Google documentation for this error [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/troubleshooting#max-instances-limit).

If this doesn't work, you may have to upgrade to a premium plan.

**OPTION 2:**

This one is the preferred so far. Unless you need to deploy to `europe-west3` for some reason, change the deployment region of your functions.

```
// So instead of this:
exports.functionName = functions.region('europe-west3').https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

// Do for example this: (europe-west1 is Belgium)
exports.functionName = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
```